# Form Load Event In Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am having a page with a form rendered multiple time with diffrent id . I want to call a on load method on it for every form . Please suggest . I am using the below method but its not working

```
OrderTemplate.LoadTile = function(){
$('#producttileform',).on('load',function(){
     alert('started');
 });    
}
```

Comment: Your selector is pointing to a single ID (_producttitleform_), so it's obvious that it will attach the event handler to just this particular form.

Comment: The above would produce a syntax error with the trailing comma after the selector.

Comment: I tried with a common class name and corrected that comma syntax too but still its not working :(

Comment: there is no load event for forms, what is your higher level objective

Comment: @charlietfl : On loading the page , I have to check some value in form and based on that value I will decide whether content needs to be replaced by a ajax call . so I was looking for a load event for every form

Comment: jquery ready handler works if forms are in page at beginning. They don't require any special load handling other than that. If you insert them with ajax would need to do whatever it is you want in success callback of ajax

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you can just use

```
$('form')
```